# No internet access on Arch fresh install

Tags: networking, wifi, arch-linux

I just freshly installed Arch on an ROG Asus laptop and successfully got everything setup. I was able to connect to the internet even after rebooting out of the live environment. I installed a few packages(git, vim etc, etc). I then went to install xfce and found that I was no longer connected to the WiFi(this laptop does not have an Ethernet port). I am not completely unable to connect to the internet as everything results in a Name or Service unknown error. I have restarted dhcpcd, resolvd and reboot several times to no effect. The interface still shows up in `ip link` and `lspci -k` as well as in `iwctl`. I am at a loss of what else to do and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking that XFCE may have some conflicting network drivers/packages, it maybe worth it to try and uninstall `iwd` and use whatever GUI networking package XFCE installs.

I remember I had a similar issue between `iwd` and `networkmanager` when installing cinnamon.

Comment: Yup, this seemes to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you `enabled` & `started` NetworkManager?

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```